# Countability of a set of polynomial functions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was trying some questions on countability of a set. Got stuck in an intermediate step.

Given $X$ = {$f$|$f$: $\Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ s.t $f$ is a polynomial function}.

I was supposed to check whether the set is countable or not.

If $f \in X$ then $f(x) = a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+..a_kx^k$

My teacher said since $f(x) \in \Bbb{N}$ for all $x \in \Bbb{N}$ implies that all coefficients of $f(x)$ will belong to $\Bbb{Q}$.

I didn't get it. Please throw light on this.

Comment: Does $\mathbb N$ contain $0?$

Comment: It is false. You can say that the coefficients will be in $\mathbb{Z}$, but these integers can be negative: for instance $f:n\mapsto n^2-2n+2$ is in $X$. Note that this counter-example works either you consider $0$ to be in $\mathbb{N}$ or not.

Comment: Show $f(n)=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ to your teacher

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Or $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ if $0\notin\Bbb N$. (I can’t believe that I didn’t think of that!) Or $\frac{n^3}3+\frac{n^2}2+\frac{n}6$.

Answer (score 2):

if $f\colon \Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is a polynomial function of degree $d$, then it completely determined by the values $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(d+1)$. There are countably many such $(d+1)$-tuples, hence the number of degree $d$ polynomial functions in $X$ is countable. Summing over the countably many possible $d$, we are still countable.

Going by the values is perhaps easier than going by the coefficients. The best you can say about those is that they are *rational*. For example, the function given by $f(n)=\frac16n^3+\frac12n^2+\frac13n$ is $\in X$ in spite of its non-integer coefficients.

Comment: Please tell how did you directly say that f(n)(that you constructed) $\in$ N for all natural numbers n?

Comment: If f is a polynomial of degree d, then how is it that it is completely determined by f(1), f(2)...f(d+1)?

Comment: @Gitika $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is always divisible by $6$, which is simplification of $f(n)$.

Comment: And for your next question, completely determined by $f(1),f(2),...,f(d+1)$ , means that , when we put the values $1,2,...,d+1$ on a $(d+1)$th degree polynomial, we get particularly $(d+1)$ numbers of polynomials,and each of which with $(d+1)$ numbers of unknowns, that means we can solve them to get the values of unknowns.

Comment: Will it have just one solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the case cardinality of $X$ , it doesn't matter whether we take $a_i$ in $\mathbb{Z} $ or in $\mathbb{N} $, the result will be same.

For simplicity, we choose $a_i$ randomly in $\mathbb{N}$.

Each $a_i$ is randomly choosen in $\mathbb{N} $,
So, for each $a_i$, there is countably infinite choice in natural numbers.

And there are finitely many $a_i$ ,$1 \le i \le n$, as $f$ is polynomial.
So, cardinality of $X$= cardinality of $\mathbb{N} × \mathbb{N} × \mathbb{N} × ..... × \mathbb{N} $ (finitely many times).

So, actually, cardinality of $X$ = $\aleph $

**Edit** : By the way,  your statement "$f(x) \in \mathbb{N} $ as $x \in \mathbb{N} $ $\implies$ $f$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{N}$ " is not true always, as all others' comments.
You can create even such polynomial which contradicts your statement. For example, $f(x)=(x-1)^3 + 4 $

Comment: This misses the point entirely: the problem was to show that the coefficients **are** in $\Bbb N$. This, however, is false, as **Fabien** noted in the comments. The best that we can hope for is to prove that they must be in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: After this, the main concept remain unchanged.  Ok, I will edit.

Comment: But you’re not even addressing the actual question. It’s clear that $X$ is countable if all of the coefficients are in $\Bbb Z$; that isn’t the problem. The problem is to show that if $f\in X$, then all of its coefficients **are** integers.

Comment: I thought main question is based on cardinality.

Comment: It isn’t. The OP doesn’t understand the teacher’s assertion that since $f(x)\in\Bbb N$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, all of the coefficients of $f$ must also be in $\Bbb N$. The OP’s question is why that is true. And in fact it **isn’t** true.